# Parsing text file in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I need to parse text file in PHP. Pleas see below, I have uploaded it as an image. I need to get the fields market in yellow.

Tried many ways, but not confidence of any. Could somebody help me?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: did you have a look at regular expressions e.g. using preg_match et al ...

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [**Stack Overflow question checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: If the format is as consistent as this then you could use `explode()` to split the data into an array. Is the data presented line-by-line as you have it, or does it come with each record on a single line?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of what you are trying to analyze, you should post the text itself and _highlight_ the required sections. That way someone would have probably have already found a simple regex to do what you need.

Comment: Does /^!/ indicate start of a record? Are all indented lines part of that record? Does /\/\d\d H \d\d/ (e.g. /15 H 10) always indicate a time? Is "*A0628/541" some sort of identifier, meaning that "/" is not always a field separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the file with regular expression and some tokenizing. it appears that your field seperater value is '/' and record separator is '\r\n\r\n'.

```
$string = "data"; //lets assume your data is contained in one string
$records = preg_split("/^[\r\n\s]+$/", $string); 
//this line assume your file contains dos formatting, change to "/\r\r/" for osx and "/\n\n/" for unix

$data = array();
foreach ($records as $record) { 
     $fields = explode("/", $records);
     $data[] = array($fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[7], $fields[16);
}

var_dump($data);
```

Please note that the record separator is important and you will need to adjust it based on the  file encoding.

Update. i have improved the record separator to be an empty line rather than two consecutive new lines.

Comment: Extracting fields by position does not seem like a very good idea to me when the individual fields have identifiers as they do here. On the other hand, the OP was not very specific about the format...

Comment: @Boise not every field has identifiers the first 4 doesn't

Comment: to me it seems like the first field, denoted by a '*' is a part number or similar, "A0628/541", or possibly "A0628" with a /541 attribute. Then you have a date and time, identified by their format, "/yy-mm-dd" and "/hh H mm" resp. Regardless of whether that is a correct assumption or not, the rest do have identifiers and should probably be parsed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$pattern[] = '#[\d]{02}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}/[\d]{2}\s[A-Z]{1}\s[\d]{2}#';
$pattern[] = '#EVENT=[A-Z]{3,}#';
$pattern[] = '#AFLR=[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}#';
$res = array();
foreach ($pattern as $key => $value){
    if (preg_match_all($value, $text, $matches)){
        $res[] = $matches[0];
    } else {
        $res[] = NULL;
    }
}
```

It looks like `EVENT` and `AFLR` are variable names that will remain constant, so I hardcoded those letters. If that's not the case, let me know.